# Crontab Won't Run xdotool

Tags: linux, bash, cron, scripting, xdotool

So, I wrote a simple script that only runs the xdotool. All it does is hit the escape key, or the hex for the escape key which is 0xff1b. However, the crontab isn't executing it for some reason. I ran the script in the terminal and it works exactly how I want it to, but crontabs just can't seem to run it. I did set the permissions to chmod u+x, just as a disclaimer. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 3
xdotool key 0xff1b
touch /writable/misc/desktop/ranscript.txt
```

crontab:

```
* * * * *      root /writable/misc/desktop/killWindow.sh
```

Comment: Is this `/etc/crontab` or a crontab created with the `crontab -e` command? You don't put the username in the latter.

Comment: X11 applications normally need to be run in the graphical login session so they inherit the `DISPLAY` environment variable. If not, you need to set the environment variable to point to the user's display. And it also needs to run from the same user so it will read the correct `.Xauthority` file.

Comment: `xdtool` may not be in the `$PATH` for the cron user. Try using the full path to `xdtool`. Is not only the script but the whole path to it accessible to the cron user? Try changing the cron entry to `bash -x /writable/...` Configure cron to send emails of the command output to see any errors.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, this is the /etc/crontab.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
* * * * * bash /writable/misc/desktop/killWindow.sh
```